# Validation of textbox that only allows numbers

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, regex, validation

I'm using Asp.net with C# (Visual Studio 2017).

- I need to create a textbox that will ONLY allow 4 digits numbers, space key, and backspace.  No special characters or alpha are allowed.
- The range has to be between 1899 to current year.
- AND it needs to validate that the years entered in the textbox are within 1899-2021.
- AND i need a popup message saying "Invalid Year" when an incorrect year is entered in the textbox.

I have tried numerous methods but nothing is working. Does anyone have codes I can use and please be clear as to where I need to insert them.

The following is one set of sample code I've tried. However, for this one, I need the codes to only allow 4 digit numbers and a space key.

I also need to know where I should insert these codes.  Hope this makes sense. Thank you!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function isValidYear() {

    var year = document.getElementById('tbxYear').value;

    if (year > 2021 || year < 1899) {
      alert("Range 1899 - 2021");
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
</script>


<asp:TextBox ID="tbxYear" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" type="number" min="1899" max="2021" step="1" onchange="isValidYear()" onpaste="return false;" BorderColor="Black" CausesValidation="True" CssClass="auto-style8" Font-Names="Arial" Height="25px"
  MaxLength="4" ValidateRequestMode="Enabled" ValidationGroup="check" Width="147px"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;<span class="auto-style16"><span class="auto-style15"><b><span style="font-size: small; font-family: Arial; color: #FF0000">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

Comment: Hi Orchid, can you edit your question with what you've tried? What frontend technology are you using?

Comment: Is this ASP.NET?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: Hayden & Theraot, I’ve edited my post to respond to your questions. Thanks

Comment: You are missing one vote to reopen the question, BTW when you want to mention a user use `@user` so he gets notified. Good luck and Welcome to SO.

Comment: @ikiK....thank you for letting me know.

Comment: @Hayden; @Theraot....I re-edited my post in response to your questions.

Comment: It has been a long time since I used ASP.NET... However, I believe the validation you want is on the client. If you are submitting to the server, you would validate twice (that is the way it is). Although MVC can allow you to write the validation once. Assuming no MVC, I would use a regular HTML input, with HTML validation (either `type="number"` with `min` and `max` attributes, or `type="text"` with `pattern` attribute). Then JavaScript for the popup. I'm not writing an answer because, well, long time no ASP.NET. By the way, I believe only first @ counts, I didn't get notification.